# Match a variable length of number with shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have files like

- _1_blabla.sql
- _35_description.sql
- _148_last_migration.sql
- structure.sql

How do I match these files starting by _variableLengthOfDigit_randomString.sql.

So far I have something like

```
find . -name '_[0-9]_*.sql'
```

But it will only match the first case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-regex` option of `find`:

```
find . -regex '.*/_[0-9]+_.*\.sql'
```

Alternatively, use bash's extended globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo _+([0-9])_*.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Using find you can use **regex**:

```
find . -regex '.*_[0-9]*_.*\.sql$'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp if you use `grep`:

```
find . | grep '^_[0-9]*_.*\.sql$'
```

The mere pattern matching of `find`'s `-name` cannot match patterns like the one you've described.

You can also use option `-regex` of modern `find` commands for this.

Comment: grep is totally unnecessary here since find has regex capabilities.

Comment: The POSIX version of `find` isn't really suitable for pipelines, as it does not have `-print0`.

Comment: Right.  But in most cases file names know how to behave anyway ;-)